# Windows Universal App Child in use error in reusable style

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a Windows Universal app that will have some reusable styles for dynamically building the UI. I create these in code and add them to a canvas I have on the page.

In the shared project I have a control in Themes\Generic.xaml, which is just a standard textblock. I can add as many of these as I want I don't get an error.

However if I declare the same Style within a resource dictionary XAML file in the Windows Phone app like so:

```
<Style TargetType="local:Widget_Generic_Text" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Widget_Generic_Text">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=dpText}" 
                               Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=dpWidth}"
                               Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=dpHeight}"                                   
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                               Foreground="#FFB1B832"  
                               FontFamily="/Fonts/#Zero Threes" 
                               FontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=dpFontSize}"
                               FontStretch="ExtraExpanded"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This file is added to the App.xaml reference like so:

```
...
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DashWidgets/Widget_Guage_Rev_Red.xaml"/>
...
```

As soon as I add a control based on this the app errors out:

```
Control userControl = new Widget_Generic_Text();
thisCanvas.Children.Add(userControl);
//Error: Element is already the child of another element
```

I've only added this one usercontrol based on the style, so I'm not sure why this is erroring out. I suspect that it's because the style is now in the phone app code as opposed to the shared apps code.

If I manually add the control in xaml code on the page then it does work fine:

```
...
<Widget_Generic_Text/>
<Widget_Generic_Text/>
...
```

How do I overcome this though? Whilst I have a simple textblock now, I have some 3rd party controls that can't sit in the shared code, due to the references yet still have to be built using code behind.

I've looked at many of the articles on this, including some SO ones, but none of them seem to cover a re-usable style. The general answer is remove it from whichever visual parent the control belongs to. Obviously I can't do this and I will need multiple of these controls on a page.

**Update: This is the code that site behind the xaml style:

```
    public sealed class Widget_Generic_Text : Control
{
    public Widget_Generic_Text()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Widget_Generic_Text);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty dpText_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("dpText", typeof(string), typeof(Widget_Generic_Text), new PropertyMetadata("No Text Defined"));
    public string dpText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(dpText_Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(dpText_Property, value);
        }
    }
```

Just before I add the control to the canvas I set some of the dependency properties with this:

```
userControl.SetBinding(Widget_Generic_Text.dpText_Property, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Main.simData.telRPM") });
```

This is following the MVVM pattern and I have about 80% + of code in the shared project.

Comment: If you're adding controls in code you're already doing something wrong.  Bindings and DataTemplates alleviate the need to do so.  I'm not sure what's behind this error, but it's clear you need to learn some MVVM. Once you learn how it works, your codebase will shrink in half, if not more. Also, a read through the Framework Design Guidelines might be in order...

Comment: I am using MVVM, I've just not referenced that to simplify what I'm showing. This control mechanism is based around the user being able to build their own dashboard. This is done in a WPF app. I then serialise the class, send it to the phone and then the display is built by hand from the list of controls in the class. I don't see what's wrong with building the UI up by hand and I'm not aware of any other way that would allow me the flexibility I'm after. Each of the dependency properties is bound to the view model, which again I've left out for simplicity. I've just updated the OP.

Comment: Okay. Some tasks, sure, are fine in the codebehind.  But you're manually doing something that could be accomplished by 1) a binding to an ItemsControl or ContentControl type paired with a 2) DataTemplate configured to display the data being bound. If you're not familiar with this pattern, you should look it up, as it avoids many of the pitfalls manipulating the UI from codebehind exposes.  [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28994128/1228) that includes a simple example of how DataTemplates work, it might help you.

Comment: @Will: Whilst that link didn't help I kept researching in a hope to understand how this would work. After reading a few articles on DrWPFs site, I started to understand how this would work. I've just implemented and barring a few issues with how I bind my UICollection that builds the control layout and binding some of the dependency properties to different viewmodel data, I have it working. So many thanks for sending me down that path. If you want to post an answer with a references to your link and the DrWPF site like the "itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate" then I'll mark this as the answer